# Sending Message From Android Emulator

Tags: android

I am developing an android messaging application. I want to send sms to url from android emulator. Is it possible? Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance,
Tushar

Comment: To url means what? A web service?

Comment: Something along these lines, I'm creating a program to send text messages, but I also want to send a SMS to an email account(as you can send a SMS to a phone from an email account). I try and use sendTextMessage with my email as the dstAddr but it doesn't send, anything special here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Android emulator console to generate an SMS message and direct it to an emulator instance:

```
sms send <senderPhoneNumber> <textmessage>
```

`<senderPhoneNumber>` is an arbitrary numeric string.

Comment: Zellux i have downloaded sms messaging code form www.mobiforge.com..Is it possible in reality to send sms programatically

Comment: @user670571 I haven't heard any free web service to send SMS